# Avoid overlapping markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker, markerclusterer

The behavior that I am looking for is to avoid the overlap of markers, that is, if I have two markers in the same coordinates, the desired behavior will be to separate them so I can see both markers and not one on top of another, also I am trying not to create a cluster of markers where I need to expand it. Any ideas? 
TiA!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster.
It groups markers and shows a "sum" of markers in the map.